# Facing error with terraform code for importing multiple runbook to azure automation account

Tags: r, azure, terraform, azure-runbook

I have created the azure automation account using terraform code. I have multiple runbooks PowerShell scripts saved in my local. I am using for.each option to import all the runbooks at a time. But I am getting some errors while running the terraform file. Please find my code below:

```
resource "azurerm_automation_runbook" "example" {
  for_each = fileset(".", "./Azure_Runbooks/*.ps1")
  name                    = ["${split("/", each.value)}"][1]
  location                = var.location
  resource_group_name     = var.resource_group
  automation_account_name = azurerm_automation_account.example.name
  log_verbose             = var.log_verbose
  log_progress            = var.log_progress
  runbook_type            = var.runbooktype
  content                 = filemd5("${each.value}")
}

Error:

Error: Invalid index
│
│   on AutomationAccount\main.tf line 51, in resource "azurerm_automation_runbook" "example":
│   51:   name                    = ["${split("/", each.value)}"][1]
│     ├────────────────
│     │ each.value will be known only after apply
│
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value: the given index is greater than   
│ or equal to the length of the collection.
```

Can someone please help how I can upload all my existing runbook scrips to the newly created automation account using terraform code.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need list in a list. So instead of

```
 name                    = ["${split("/", each.value)}"][1]
```

it should be

```
 name                    = split("/", each.value)[1]
```

Comment: Hi Marcin, Thanks for the reply. I made the changes as suggested but this time the error got changed. it is saying like invalid script name. Can you please guide me how I can rename the script again please:

Comment: Error:
Error: invalid value for name (The name can contain only letters, numbers, underscores and dashes. The 
name must begin with a letter. The name must be less than 64 characters.)
│
│   with module.Oneshareautomationaccount.azurerm_automation_runbook.example["Azure_Runbooks/VMresize.ps1"],
│   on AutomationAccount\main.tf line 51, in resource "azurerm_automation_runbook" "example":
│   51:   name                    = split("/", each.value)[1]

Comment: I found like it is not considering the * letter if we keep in the file path:
for_each = fileset(".", "./Azure_Runbooks/*.ps1"), I have multiple scripts under Azure_Runbooks folder. Kindly suggest us how we can pull all the files at a time.

Comment: @LokeshM If you have new error, new question should be asked. My answer correctly addresses your problem that you originally reported.